# visual studio Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined error

Tags: visual-studio

my visual studio automatically inserts this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script></form>
```

code on debugging (it is a default.aspx with default masterpage), which seems to cause the error message with the content

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined

to appear any time I debug a project.

Does anyone know how to solve this visual studio problem? I am not using ajax. It is just default.

Also breakpoints are not hit!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a script manager to the master page.

Comment: this did not solve my problem and I don't see why I would need one as long as I don't use ajax

Comment: Your using some type of control that requires a script manager, hence the "Sys" object reference.

Comment: As thinkdevcode suggests, this can also happen if your code attempts to reference Sys before the script is loaded.

Comment: ok, i removed the masterpage and now it is working, but my breakpoints are still not hit. should I reinstall VS?

Comment: Mouse over the break point after running the application. What does the tool tip say?

Comment: the breakpoint will not be hit. The source code is different from the original version. why would i get this?

Comment: Theres a number of reasons. Your best bet it to ask a new question for this topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a scriptmanager on the page and it still doesnt work, then place the `<script>` tag some place after where you put your scriptmanager.